# How to manually change date in Ionic2-Calendar?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Whenever I am trying to assign it like:

```
this.calendar.currentDate = new Date();
```

it doesn't work and doesn't switch to this certain date, so how to switch date from code?

Edit: 
Ok it's weird because it does work like this when i simply write that to code, but it doesn't work when I am using this with Ionic's:

```
dateSwapModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  this.calendar.currentDate = data.Date;
})
```